# Convert Joda-Time `DateTime` with timezone to DateTime without timezone?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

Given a [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) for example `2015-07-09T05:10:00+02:00` using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)?

How can I convert it to local time, meaning adding the timezone to the time itself.
Desired output: `2015-07-09T07:10:00`

I tried `dateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)` but that did not give the desired result.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What @Nazgul said is right, but in case all you want to achieve is a "wall-time" in UTC zone you can do something like that:

```
DateTime dateTimePlus2 = DateTime.parse("2015-07-09T05:10:00+02:00");
System.out.println(dateTimePlus2);

DateTime dateTimeUTC = dateTimePlus2.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(dateTimeUTC);

LocalDateTime localDateTimeUTC = dateTimeUTC.toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println(localDateTimeUTC);
```

Result:

```
2015-07-09T05:10:00.000+02:00
2015-07-09T03:10:00.000Z        ("Z" == Zulu tz == UTC)
2015-07-09T03:10:00.000
```

As you can see, the time is not "07:10" as you expected, because UTC+2 zone is two hours **ahead** of UTC. Converting to UTC **subtracts** 2 hours.

Answer (score 21):

Adding a bit more info and examples to the correct answers ([accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27382126/642706) and [other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27381733/642706)).

**UPDATE** Added section at end on java.time classes. These supplant Joda-Time.

## Purpose of `LocalDateTime`

You may be confused about the purpose of [`LocalDateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html).

If trying to represent a date-time value using "wall clock time" as seen by someone in a locality looking at their own clock and calendar, then adjust the time zone of the `DateTime` object to suit the desired locality.

LocalDateTime is not meant for a particular locality but for the general idea of date+time. For example, "This year's Christmas starts at midnight on December 25, 2014". Conceptually, that is a LocalDateTime, intended to mean different moments in Paris than Montréal and Auckland.

## Adjusting Time Zone

Use the `DateTimeZone` class in Joda-Time to adjust to a desired time zone. Joda-Time uses immutable objects. So rather than change the time zone ("mutate"), we instantiate a new DateTime object based on the old but with the desired difference (some other time zone).

Use proper [time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Generally a `continent/cityOrRegion`.

```
DateTimeZone zoneParis = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTimeZone zoneMontréal = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTimeZone zoneAuckland = DateTimeZone.forID( "Pacific/Auckland" );
```

Parse string, assign a time zone, adjust to other time zones.

```
DateTime dateTimeParis = new DateTime( "2015-07-09T05:10:00+02:00" , zoneParis );
DateTime dateTimeMontréal = dateTimeParis.withZone( zoneMontréal );
DateTime dateTimeAuckland = dateTimeParis.withZone( zoneAuckland );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "dateTimeParis: " + dateTimeParis );
System.out.println( "dateTimeMontréal: " + dateTimeMontréal );
System.out.println( "dateTimeAuckland: " + dateTimeAuckland );
```

When run.

```
dateTimeParis: 2015-07-09T05:10:00.000+02:00
dateTimeMontréal: 2015-07-08T23:10:00.000-04:00
dateTimeAuckland: 2015-07-09T15:10:00.000+12:00
```

## Localize Using Formatted Strings

Joda-Time can translate to a particular locale’s language and customary style when creating a string representation of your date-time object.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterMontréal = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FF" ).withZone( zoneMontréal ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
String outputMontréal = formatterMontréal.print( dateTimeParis );
System.out.println( "outputMontréal: " + outputMontréal );
```

When run:

```
outputMontréal: mercredi 8 juillet 2015 23 h 10 EDT
```

---

## java.time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. The Joda-Time framework inspired java.time, so concepts are quite similar.

`ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset` are the two classes to represent a time zone and [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) respectively. An offset is merely a number of hours and minutes and seconds. A time zone is an offset *plus* a set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

```
ZoneId zoneParis = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" );
ZoneId zoneMontreal = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZoneId zoneAuckland = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" );
```

[image]

The primary date-time classes in java.time are:

- [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) – A moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).
- [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) – An `Instant` plus a [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html).
- [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) – An `Instant` plus a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).

The java.time classes use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings representing date-time values. So no need to specify a formatting pattern with such inputs.

This input here indicates an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) but not a full time zone. So we parse as an `OffsetDateTime` rather than a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2015-07-09T05:10:00+02:00" );
```

As the basic building-block of java.time, always in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) by definition, you may want to extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();  // `Instant` is always in UTC by definition.
```

You can adjust into a time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtParis = odt.atZoneSameInstant( zoneParis );
ZonedDateTime zdtMontreal = odt.atZoneSameInstant( zoneMontreal );
ZonedDateTime zdtAuckland = zdtMontreal.withZoneSameInstant( zoneAuckland );
```

Localize via the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeformatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );
String output = zdtMontreal.format( f );
```

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/Rbcv9l).

> odt: 2015-07-09T05:10+02:00
>
> instant: 2015-07-09T03:10:00Z
>
> zdtParis: 2015-07-09T05:10+02:00[Europe/Paris]
>
> zdtMontreal: 2015-07-08T23:10-04:00[America/Montreal]
>
> zdtAuckland: 2015-07-09T15:10+12:00[Pacific/Auckland]
>
> output: mercredi 8 juillet 2015 23 h 10 EDT

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for that detailed insight! This "wall clock time" is exactly what I need, but I don't know the timezone the time shall be in, just the time itself. So I'll probably have to go for LocalDateTime...

Comment: Very illuminating.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime without timezone dosnt make sense. DateTime are always relative to the timezone in which they are used. Without the timezone information a date time combination makes no sense for the geography as such. raw timestamp millies can however be accessed as the number of millies gone since 1st Jan 1970 but any concrete date time combinations must have a timezone with it.

Comment: Which joda object could I use as an alternative that only has date+time, but no timezone?

Comment: No I don't think you can. But what you can do it make timezones for all concerning DateTimes same (preferably all to UTC) so that while comparing or doing any operations on them the timezone is not a differentiating factor.