# How to create a new LocalDateTime containing ZERO timezone?

Tags: java, jodatime

`new LocalDateTime("1999-12-31T00:00:00Z");`

When I try to create this datetime, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "1999-12-31T00:00:00Z" is malformed at "Z"
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParserBucket.doParseMillis(DateTimeParserBucket.java:187)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseMillis(DateTimeFormatter.java:780)
    at org.joda.time.convert.StringConverter.getPartialValues(StringConverter.java:87)
    at org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.<init>(LocalDateTime.java:414)
    at org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.<init>(LocalDateTime.java:358)
```

How can I then parse that date to LocalDateTime?

Comment: You may be confused about the purpose of LocalDateTime. If trying to represent a date-time value using "wall clock time" as seen by someone in a locality looking at their own clock and calendar, then generate a String representing the date-time value by using a [DateTimeFormatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). LocalDateTime is not meant for a particular locality but for the general idea of date+time. Example as "This year's Christmas starts at midnight on December 25, 2014" which is a different moment in Paris than Montréal and Auckland.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Joda DateTime with timezone to DateTime without timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381626/convert-joda-datetime-with-timezone-to-datetime-without-timezone)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I then parse that date to LocalDateTime?

You can't - `LocalDateTime` represents a date and time that does not have an associated timezone at all.  If you have a timestamp that is anchored to a timezone (UTC in this case) then you should be using `DateTime` instead of `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: OK that makes sense, so I'll probably create a DateTime and then convert to LocalDateTime.